# How have past inaugurations affected markets?

Tags: united-states

On January 20th a new President will be inaugurated for the United States. How have past inaugurations affected markets?

Answer (score 8):

If markets (and presidents-elect) are both rational, there should be no effect at all, since the inauguration can be predicted with a very high confidence level as soon as the election results are known.

Of course, either of the above assumptions may be false...

Answer (score 6):

> How have past inaugurations affected markets?

Typically, very little.

This might help:
[a look back to 1920 using the Dow to see how the market has reacted to past inaugurations](http://quantifiableedges.blogspot.com/2009/01/inauguration-day-new-hope-for-market.html)

But remember, the future is unknowable.

Comment: In addition to adding a page summary, it would be interesting to add the Obama inauguration to your answer.